# Push Poison Message to backout Queue[IBM MQ] after certain retries with Spring retry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq

Step 1:
Consuming Message from IBM MQ and processing it.

Step 2: If some message gets  failed to process then it will be retried for certain times using spring Retry, but if still issue persists then want to move  those messages to Backout Queue.

Note: Spring Retry Part has been done, I want help in pushing Poison Message to Backout Queue after those retries.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Have you looked at -https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=applications-handling-poison-messages-in-mq-classes-jms -

Comment: Why was this question closed.  It was a very clear question if you understand the technology and in fact had a very clear answer posted almost a day before it was closed.

Comment: Agree @JoshMc - I don't understand why this question was closed either. It is a perfectly well asked question, and also already answered very well too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BOTHRESH and BOQNAME attributes of MQ Queue. Once the message backout count reaches the value set on BOTHRESH, the message is moved to backout queue by MQ JMS. More details on poison message handling are [here](http://%20https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=applications-handling-poison-messages-in-mq-classes-jms%20-).

I don't know much about Spring Retry. But if you use MQ JMS Backout mechanism, I wonder if Spring Retry is still required.

Comment: Thanks For your Answer. So what i got from your point is if i set these mentioned parameters while creating queues we are all set, no extra code configurations needed from java/service standpoint, right? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That's correct. Note that application must get messages in a transacted session and if processing fails, application must rollback the transaction. Committing the transaction will remove message from a queue.

Comment: Open Ibm MQ Explorer, right-click on your queue, properties.  See what you have for Backout Threshold, and backout requeue queue.  The Threshold should not be zero.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=wwmcja-handling-poison-messages-in-websphere-mq-classes-jms

Comment: A threshold of 1 means the message will be tried only (1 time) and if transaction rollsback, will be put on the configured backout requeue queue.  Threshold of 3, means 3 tries.